# How trigger 2 events with 1 selector?

Tags: jquery

When the user clicks on "a.open-popup", I need some HTML to change (1 function) and a simplelightbox to pop open (another function). How do I do this? I can only get 1 of the 2 functions to trigger.

HTML:

```
<div>
        <p class="plan-msg">Plan message</p>
        <div class="completed-button">
               <a href="#popup01" class="open-popup">Did it</a>
        </div>  
</div>
```

jQuery function 1 (HTML changes):

```
jQuery('a.open-popup').click(function(event){
var $parent = jQuery(this).parent();

    event.preventDefault();
    $parent.siblings('.plan-msg').remove();
    $parent.removeClass('completed-button')
                .addClass('add-inv-button ')
                .html('Add to Plan');

});
```

jQuery function 2 (open simplelightbox):

```
$(function(){
    jQuery("a.open-popup").click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           jQuery(this).simpleLightbox({ closeLink:'a.close' });
     });
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery("a.open-popup").simpleLightbox({ closeLink:'a.close' });
```

you're missing the `.click()`.  It should be:

```
jQuery("a.open-popup").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  jQuery(this).simpleLightbox({ closeLink:'a.close' });
});
```

This *will* work in conjunction with your other handler, which was already correct.

---

**edit**

ok, the following will work **if** you have included the code for `simpleLightbox` **before** this block of code runs:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery("a.open-popup").simpleLightbox({
        closeLink: 'a.close'
    });

    jQuery('a.open-popup').click(function(event) {
        var $parent = jQuery(this).parent();

        event.preventDefault();
        $parent.siblings('.plan-msg').remove();
        $parent.removeClass('completed-button')
            .addClass('add-inv-button')
            .html('Add to Plan');

    });
});
```

I have posted a working example of this on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fZPjg/.

Note: I have used the `$(function() {...})` notation to be consistent with your original post, but jQuery recommends that you use `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` instead.  Presently the two forms function identically.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I click on a.open-popup, the browser does not open the div #popup01. Instead, it goes to www.mydomain.com/#popup01 and the screen is blank.

Comment: The page is navigating because it's the default behavior of clicking on the link.  I've made an edit above which will prevent the navigation from happening.  Once that's done, if you're still having trouble, please post a link to the documentation of the `simpleLightbox` plugin you're using, and I'll see if I can help further.

Comment: I've updated the code above to include event.preventDefault for BOTH jQuery functions. However, now I'm back to my original problem. Only one of the 2 events trigger, but not both. Here's a link to the simpleLightbox code: http://bit.ly/fp7FjY

Comment: both of your handlers are running (try putting an `alert('whatever')` inside each handler function).  The problem is that `jQuery(this).simpleLightbox({ closeLink:'a.close' })` does not cause the lightbox to open -- I assumed, from your original post, that it did trigger the opening of the lightbox, but in actuality, it just installs a click handler, which in turn triggers the lightbox onclick.  You probably need to go back to something like what you started with.  I'll see if I make an example for you.

Comment: just posted an update that includes a new example, and a link to a working demo at jsFiddle.

Comment: @Lee - thank you so much for all your efforts! The code is almost working as expected. Is there a way that I sequence the functions so that function 1 happens first and then function 2? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`.trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to fire a custom trigger when you are inside the handler of the first event, here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9m9z/1/)